# How can I populate a local static HTML document with with data from an external source?

Tags: html

OK, so please forgive me if this is a tired question from a born again newbie... I have created an HTML document that I plan to use as a template for items which will then be inserted into ebay listings. All of the item details will be stored in a database of some sort. (most likely a CSV file output from Excel)

My question is this and I need some direction from the crowd: What is the best method to extract the info from the data source, find the appropriate place-holder in the HTML and place the data in?

I am really hoping to be able to use some sort of routine to do this that can run on my PC and output the HTML files.  I've been beating my head against the internet for a couple of evenings trying to find something, but all of the solutions I have found are dynamic in nature.  I need something that runs locally before the HTML is pushed to ebay. Right now I am looking for the right trailhead for my journey.  *What do I need to learn next?*

I've placed the draft of the [HTML document](https://github.com/colost8rams/Listing-Template.git) on github if you would like further reference. (note, still a work in progress!) The info that would be transferred in would be the image url's in the gallery and the item details on the tabs on the right.

Comment: This can be done in nearly any programming language, so you'll probably want to choose the programming language you are most familiar with. Which language is that? If you tell us, we can focus our answers on this language.

Comment: Hi @meriton To be honest, I was kinda hoping for a "canned" solution of sorts.  Most of my programming experience is in Fortran (did I just age myself?) Labview and VBA.  That said, I am just starting to re-immerse myself in web design so I am starting to learn some JS and PHP.  I was thinking of investigating a static site generator like DocPad, perhaps that may offer me some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A secondary option is to use Papa Parse (http://papaparse.com/) which is built for handling CSV parsing (both local and remote).

You'll need to understand basic Javascript (or recognize general logic / patterns) and from there you can:

1. Add the source script file in script tags at the bottom of your HTML document before the closing body tag.
2. Add the following code in a secondary script (e.g. main.js) and link it in the same scripts location:

   var results = Papa.parse(fileInput.files[0], {
       complete: function(results) {
           console.log(results);
       }
   });

   // The above simply logs the results of the parse function to your console (if you have Chrome you can find this under Tools)

Comment: This is certainly worth investigating further.  Thanks @MrBullets.  My issue is that ebay does not allow any javascript, PHP, etc. in listings, its supposed to be purely HTML that you are essentially pasting into an iframe... So, I think what I need is a static site generator?  Something that can take Template + data and spit out HTML doc that I could then paste into ebay.  I am going to go and snoop around on some of the other sites on the stack now because my search is getting off topic.  Thanks for the input!  I will definitely keep these techniques in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you're working with extracting data you're going to be pulling it from a database. This is why most of your research results in dynamically related questions.

Ask yourself, how are you going to insert your items into a database if you are unaware of how to retrieve them? They're effectively one of the same.

If you have any PHP experience whatsoever or if you're able to recognize patterns and follow the trail, a framework such as Medoo (http://medoo.in/) makes it extremely easy to get your information in and out on to your overall template page.

For Medoo, you can use their Getting Started section for more information but here's a quick run-down.

1. Copy the medoo.php file from the Medoo website and put it in a folder.
2. Create a new PHP file called insert.php and add the following:

   ```
   require  'medoo.php'; //same location as insert.php

   $database = new medoo([
     // all of this you can create with standard shared hosting 
     // simply change the info inside of the quotes
     'database_type' => 'mysql',
     'database_name' => 'name',
     'server' => 'localhost',
     'username' => 'your_username',
     'password' => 'your_password',

     // optional -- you shouldn't need to change any of these
     'port' => 3306,
     'charset' => 'utf8',

     'option' => [
       PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
     ]
   ]);

   // Now to insert a record into your MySQL database
   // "account" is the table, and "user_name" is the field
   // you want to insert a value into, e.g. "foo"

   $database->insert("account", [
     "user_name" => "foo",
     "email" => "foo@bar.com"
   ]);
   ```
3. You can use your hosting provider tools to add a database, add a user to that database, login to their MySQL admin editor (e.g. PHPMyAdmin), select the database and then insert your fields from there.
4. Once the above is in place and on your server, simply navigate to insert.php and you'll see the record populate in the fields you've chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I will definitely take a look at the link you provided.  _Are there any examples out there_ that illustrate how medoo would be used?  As for the data itself, most of it is already resident in an excel file, which is why my first thought was to use CSV rather than teaching myself SQL.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect setting it up and as well as inserting content. Let me know if that helps!